# "To put in labour" meaning

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

I've met a phrase in a book "(someone)...puts in labour", top results of googling didn't bring me to understanding the meaning. What does it mean?

Edit: The book is  Bhrigu Samhita by T.M. Rao, indian author. Here is a screen shot with the text. [View on Google Books.](https://books.google.com/books?id=7pNxr9blvjgC&lpg=PT176&ots=mxLzreSc0O&dq=is%20very%20energetic%20and%20has%20the%20great%20power%20of%20intellect%20is%20not%20gentle%20talks%20very&pg=PT176#v=onepage&q=is%20very%20energetic%20and%20has%20the%20great%20power%20of%20intellect%20is%20not%20gentle%20talks%20very&f=false)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Without the full context it's hard to ascertain whether the usage is "valid" or not, but my first thought is native speakers wouldn't usually use ***labour*** in that way. More likely is something like [*He puts in **effort***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+puts+in+effort%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), meaning *He makes an effort, His contribution [to some project/task] is **effort** [as opposed to brains, money, enthusiasm, etc.]* Basically, *to put in X = to **contribute** X*

Comment: Thank you, looks like a good answer which I would vote for.

Comment: I'd rather see you give us the full context (or at least, a *link*) for wherever you found your cited text. It would obviously make a difference if we knew whether the writer was a native speaker, for example, because "labour" might feasibly be valid in some contexts (but probably it's not a very good choice of words).

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, you are right about the author is not native speaker. I believe you are also correct about the meaning. I added more information to the question. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: This is from a horoscope and is describing the qualities of a person born under that sign. I think that "is a hard worker" would fit the style of the text while being more clear.

Comment: Horoscope; exactly! +1, @Phil! I personally think this is basically the wierd language of fortellers. They like abnormal words! "Put in effort" can never affect the audience like "put in labour". Or who knows? Maybe it was only because s/he wasn't native.

Comment: @MARamezani: No, this is *not* an example of "the weird language of fortunetellers". It's just clumsy English from a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

As MARemazani states in their comment, fortunetelling tends to use very non-specific language. This allows a statement to be open to enough interpretation that any person who reads it can identify with it.

As FumbleFingers states in their comment, *"putting in labour"* means *"put in or contribute effort"*. While the author may have been a bit clumsy about their translation, I doubt the original was any more specific. The language is intentionally open-ended so that any reader will be able to identify with it. Reading the rest of the paragraph, clumsy English notwithstanding, the non-specific language is consistent.

- We all like to think of ourselves as energetic and intelligent.
- We all have to put at least a little effort into our daily lives, even if that effort is purely mental.
- Most people spend money, and the word *much* is so vague here as to be useless.
- Most people would like to believe their children are clever.
- Gentle and talkative are highly subjective without any context.
- With the possible exceptions of orphans and genetic clones, we all have mothers with whom we've disagreed at least once in our lives; and even then, those exceptions can still have mother figures or adopted parents.

So, just to succinctly reiterate, the phrase "(someone) puts in labour" means "(someone) puts in or contributes effort". And thanks to MARemazani, FumbleFingers and Phil for the *labour they put in* to this question with their comments.